# How to "rethrow" event of private field?

Tags: c#, events

I need to attach to event of the private field of the class like that:

```
MyClass myInstance = ...
... 
myInstance.checkbook.RangeMissing += new EventHandler<RangeMissingEventArgs>(RangeMissing);
```

To do that I have to do `checkbook public`. However I want to keep `checkbook private`, I only want to catch "RangeMissing" event.

So I need kind of "rethrow" in MyClass class of event RangeMissing?

Of course I can do that "explicitly" (attach MyClass to checkbook, catch RangeMissing event, throw new RangeMissing event), but I think it's too complicated.

Do I have design problem? Should I make `checkbook` public? Should I just write 10 lines of extra code and just rethrow event explicitly in `MyClass` class?

Comment: You should hide `checkbook` field and create a new Event inside `MyClass` called `RangeMissing`. Then inside `MyClass` register for `checkbook.RangeMissing` notification and call `this.RangeMissing(etc.)` inside the handling.

Comment: We don't throw events, we raise them.

Comment: I think that you should add this ten lines for encapsulations sake. This way RangeMissing becomes event of your class and nobody else knows (and should not know) what fired it.

Comment: ...yes, I think you / we need to know the design and what you're after to achieve  
@HenkHolterman good one :)  +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have two options here:

1. As Tigran suggested, handle the event in your class by raising another event:

   ```
   class MyClass
   {
       public event EventHandler<RangeMissingEventArgs> CheckbookRangeMissing =
           delegate { };

       public MyClass()
       {
           // initialize checkbook

           checkbook.RangeMissing += OnCheckbookRangeMissing;
       }

       private void OnCheckbookRangeMissing(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           CheckbookRangeMissing(this, e)
       }
   }
   ```

   Be careful with this approach, because it might cause memory leaks if the lifetime of `checkbook` is longer than of `MyClass`. In that case, you need to unsubscribe from the event when you're done with `MyClass` (probably in a `Dispose()` method).
2. Create an event that forwards all subscribers to the event on `checkbook`:

   ```
   class MyClass
   {
       public event EventHandler<RangeMissingEventArgs> CheckbookRangeMissing 
       {
           add
           {
               checkbook.RangeMissing += value;
           }
           remove
           {
               checkbook.RangeMissing -= value;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: To accomplish #1 without memory leakage, you'd probably want to implement a custom event and count the number of remaining handlers in the `remove` implementation.  This is different from option #2 in that you still substitute the wrapper `sender`.  Note also that option #2 allows the `private` checkbook object to leak to all subscribers via the `sender` argument.

Comment: Also, isn't a `null` check needed?

Comment: You're right, I forgot a `null` check. I like to avoid it using the `delegate { }` “trick”.

Comment: @svick actually I like `option 2` because it much more readable. Ignoring the fact that private `checkbook` object is leak are there any other problems with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have design problems, nor that are visible from the post at least. 
The easiest and more streightforward solution, imo, would be

- first leave `checkbox` as *private*
- and inside `MyClass` re-raise an event raised from `checkbox`

In this way you will hide a checkbox and expose an event to your `MyClass` consumer. Plus you can, if need, change a delegate and deliver to consumer of `MyClass` a delegate with different from the `checkbox` event parameters.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution for what you need is to use Rx - if you're not afraid to introduce new technology into the picture (there is a pretty stable release out already and with go live license)
i.e. using

```
IObservable<DataType> RangeMissing;
```

...which is implemented (raised) by the referenced private field's class.
Then the parent class just needs to wrap that into a very simple property (public)...

```
public IObservable<DataType> RangeMissing {get{return _privateField.RangeMissing;} }
```

...that's the most 'green' way of handling events and the whole framework is invented for such purposes (easily manipulating events, w/o requiring all the subscribe/unsubscribe and imperative coding - e.g. even the simple wrapper like yours becomes a problem, small one but unnecessary code is needed to be written).
You can install Rx through NuGet into the project (works for .NET 4, VS 2010)

That's what I think is recommended from the design perspective,
other than that you might want to just wrap as suggested, or make a more elaborate wrapper for such a purpose (but Rx does that much better) - or rethink some design decisions, class responsibilities - or whether to expose events specifically via a specific implementation etc. (for this we'd need to know much more details, each design is specific).
hope this helps